# Median of a fair $6$ sided die, rolling once

Tags: probability

If you roll a $6$ sided die once.  What would be the median outcome?

I made a table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & P(X= x) & F(x) = P(X \le x)  \\ \hline
1 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ \hline
2 & 1/6  & 2/6 \\ \hline
3 & 1/6 & 3/6 = 1/2 \\ \hline
4 & 1/6 & 4/6 \\ \hline
5 & 1/6 & 5/6 \\ \hline
6 & 1/6 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

So by definition, whatever value the first time $F(x) \ge 1/2$ will be the median. I thought the median would be $3$ then.  But $F(x) = 1/2$  for any $x$ s.t $3 \le x < 4$ and if you roll the die many times it will converge to $3.5$.  So then there would be infinitely many medians between $3$ and $4$?  Can anyone explain more on this for me?

Comment: Yep, there is no unique median here, unless you restrict the possible values for the median to $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition a [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions) connected with a random variable $X$ (or if you like its distribution) is a real number $m$ that satisfies the inequalities:$$P(X\geq m)\geq0.5\text{ and }P(X\leq m)\geq0.5$$ So in your case every element of $[3,4]$ is a median.